# Azure SQL Data Factory Copy Activity with Sink Stored Procedure

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory

I cant get this going and seem not to find solutions on this forum. I am new to Azure

I have successfully established a direct SQL Query copy activity from on Prem SQL Server to Azure SQL.
[image]

When I proceed to edit to include a Stored Procedure it fails. I have created a data type and stored procedure as follows in the Azure Sql;

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Patch] AS TABLE(
    [BaseKey] int,
    [GISKey] [varchar](10),
    [ActiveFrom] datetime
)
DROP PROC IF EXISTS dbo.spCopyPatch
GO
CREATE PROC dbo.spCopyPatch
@Patch dbo.Patch READONLY,
@BaseKey int,
@GISKey varchar(10),
@ActiveFrom datetime
AS
INSERT INTO dbo.Patch( BaseKey,GISKey,ActiveFrom)
VALUES(@BaseKey,@GISKey,@ActiveFrom);
GO
```

I then proceeded to edit the copy activity Sink. It is able to pick up the Stored Procedure OK;

[image]

However this fails on debug: Am I getting it right or missing something?

Your help highly appreciated in advance.

Comment: Hey @wwnde, Can you please mention why you want to use stored procedure in sink ?
via copy activity you can directly map the source and sink table columns.
So understanding your use case would help in identifying the solution

Comment: @Nandan Once the pipeline is finalized and working, the intention is to modify the stored procedure often to facilitate varied transformations as will be dictated by business owners' needs. This can vary from time to time. I started of with a straight forward direct copy to understand how it works.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: @wBob  Thanks for being willing to help. I sorted it out. Shared my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved this and wrote direct from OnPrem SQL Server to Azure SQL Server.

**Step 1.** Update Source with the a dataset drawn from the SQL.

[image]

**Step 2.** Updated My Stored Procedure  to what is highlighted in green below

[image]

**Step 3.** Populate Sink in order and shown below

[image]

Debug Copy activity and you have it

[image]